# Editing XML file in Silverlight does not work, but why?

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, file, editing

Im trying to open and edit XML file inside Silverlight element, but I can't edit it.

My XML file (Customers.xml) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customers>
  <customer>Joe</customer>
  <customer>Barrel</customer>
</customers>
```

And my C# logic:

[...]

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Customers.xml");
            xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("customer", "Stephano")); //here I wish it to add Stephano as a customer.
            using (var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (var stream = file.OpenFile("Customers.xml", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    xdoc.Save(stream); //and here I wish it to save it to the file
                }
            }

PopulateCustomersList();
```

/\ here is a function that is used to display the content of XML file, it goes:

```
private void PopulateCustomersList()
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.XmlResolver = new XmlXapResolver();
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("Customers.xml");
            reader.MoveToContent();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "customer")
                {
                    //OutputTextBlock.Text = reader.GetAttribute("first");
                    customersList.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem()
                    {
                        Content = reader.ReadInnerXml()
                    });
                }

                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.Name == "customers")
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
```

In my xaml file I have

```
<ListBox x:Name="customersList" />
```

so it gets displayed, but the problem is that only Joe and Barrel gets to be displayed and where is Stephano?

I got this code from various tutorials and forums, I don't quite understand it, I know it may be strange way to do that, but I just can't find out how to do that and I'm trying all sort of things. The funniest thing is that I found on many forums a way to save the file, which looks like this:
`xdoc.Save("Customers.xml");` but my Visual Studio says that the arguments are wrong, because it is a string. How am I supposed to tell him that its a file?

Answer (score 0):

Okay:

.Save() saves the current XDocument, I.E it's going to save the XML file you loaded up here

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Customers.xml");
```

So it should be something like (this is coded without any knowledge more than you provided)

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Customers.xml");
        xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("customer", "Stephano"));
xdoc.Save();
PopulateCustomersList(xdoc);

private void PopulateCustomersList(XDocument xdoc)
     {
         foreach(XElement in element xdoc.Root.Elements("customer"))
         {
            customersList.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem()
             {
                Content = (string)element;
             }
         }
     }
```